# Create database connection sql server 2014 from metada using talend repository

Tags: windows-authentication, talend, sql-server-2014-express

I can't get my database connection using a Windows authentication.
I get this error: `Connection refused.`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have let the textbox login and password to empty and server name localhost

Comment: some code pleeze? Or settings or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use windows authentication in Talend there are several steps:

1. download ntlmauth.dll from here:

   http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=33291
2. unzip and place in the same directory as you are running you Talend Studio executable.  There is a 32 and 64 bit dll, but they are the same dll so you should be able to use either.
3. in your connections keep username and password empty.  (in Talend Studio the empty password will show as 4 asterisks).
4. run job.

If you get an error like connection refused, then you have followed the above steps and your issues is related to a network configuration or permissions.  The first thing I would check it to make sure you are able to connect to the sql server using the correct port (1433 is the default).  Try Telnet.  If you get something like 'Could not open connection to the host...Connect failed" then the port may be blocked by the SQL Server's firewall, or may be behind a network firewall.

You can also use SQL Server Management Studio to connect and run the same query you are trying to run via Talend.  If you cannot connect to the SQL server you should get a similar message as produced by Talend.

If you cannot connect via management studio, this could be a permissions issue in the SQL Server for your domain user account.  Try getting admin rights to both the physical server and the SQL server instance.  If you can then connect, lower your rights until you get the issue again.  Then you will know what level of rights are needed for your connection. (I don't recommend leaving the elevated privileges- it can be helpful for troubleshooting but then should be lowered down using the least-privileges principle).

Answer (score 0):

From a Mac/Linux server:

1. Fill the username, password, etc. fields
2. In the "Additional parameters" field, add the following:

   > domain=your_domain;useNTLMv2=true

Answer (score 0):

define the instance as parameter.
You can type it on the server form or additional form.
On the server for you can type like localhost;instance=yourInstance